# Hibernate and Spring Data with Spring DBUnit on HSQLDB - Unable to delete due to foreign key constraint

Tags: hibernate, hsqldb, spring-data-jpa, spring-test-dbunit

I'm using Hibernate and Spring Data to model a very simple domain:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5501812656863255674L;

    @Id
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column
    private String forename;

    @Column
    private String surname;

    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private UserRole role;

    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
    private List<Team> teams;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Team implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3734641391628154428L;

    private static final BigDecimal STARTING_BUDGET = new BigDecimal(100);

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

I then have an 'updateUser' method in a data service which does as it is named.  The idea is that to add a Team to a User, this method would be used and the cascading would result in the Team being persisted in the database.

```
@Override
    public void updateUser(final User user) throws IntegrationException {

        if (userRepository.exists(user.getEmailAddress())) {
            userRepository.save(user);
        } else {
            throw new IntegrationException(IntegrationExceptionCode.USER_NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

I'm then unit testing this method using a HSQLDB database and Spring DBUnit to setup the initial database contents and the expected DB contents:

**Initial DB Content Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <User emailAddress="user1@test.com" forename="User" surname="One" role="MANAGER" />
    <Player />
    <User_Team />
    <Team />
</dataset>
```

**Expected DB Content Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<dataset>
    <User emailAddress="user1@test.com" forename="User" surname="One" role="MANAGER" />
    <Player />
    <Team id="1" name="Test Team" totalScore="0" status="INCOMPLETE" remainingBudget="100" />
    <User_Team User_emailAddress="user1@test.com" Teams_id="1" />
</dataset>
```

I then have two tests: one which tests the update success; one which tests that a user which is not already in the system can't be updated.

**Success Test**

```
@Test
@ExpectedDatabase("UserData-WithTeam.xml")
public void testUpdateUser_AddedTeam_Success() throws Exception {
    // arrange
    final User user = UserTestDataBuilder.aManager(VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, "User", "One").withTeam().build();

    // act
    userDataService.updateUser(user);

    // assert - done by @ExpectedDatabase annotation
}
```

**'User Does Not Exist' Test**

```
@Test
    public void testUpdateUser_AddedTeam_UserDoesNotExist() throws Exception {
        // arrange
        thrownException.expect(IntegrationException.class);
        thrownException.expect(CustomIntegrationExceptionMatcher.hasCode(IntegrationExceptionCode.USER_NOT_FOUND));

        final User user = UserTestDataBuilder.aManagerWithEmailAddress(INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS).withTeam().build();

        // act
        userDataService.updateUser(user);

        // assert
        Assert.fail("Exception expected");
    }
```

The 'success' test works fine.  However, the 'failure case' test errors with the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; FK_RVG5KHM9RO439HI17HPAUV5KG table: USER_TEAM
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.dbunit.database.statement.SimpleStatement.executeBatch(SimpleStatement.java:69)
    at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:126)
    at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:194)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:66)
    at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:186)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:249)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.junit.rules.ExpectedException$ExpectedExceptionStatement.evaluate(ExpectedException.java:239)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action; FK_RVG5KHM9RO439HI17HPAUV5KG table: USER_TEAM
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.performReferentialActions(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.delete(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.executeDeleteStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDML.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 32 more
```

It seems to be suggesting that it can't tear down the test data added in the 'success' test (and I've added the @Ignore annotation to the success test and the failure test passes).  My question is why?  My cascade on the @OneToMany relationship is set to ALL so all entities saved as part of the User-Team relationship should be removed.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a Integrity constraint in `USER_TEAM` table: `UPDATE NO ACTION` 
that's why gives `java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: integrity constraint violation: foreign key no action;`